# Add inline image alongwith other text in the email body using C# console application

Tags: c#, image

Having an issue adding an image to email as an embedded image in the body. I already have the email message that pulls the name and emailid for an user dynamically.

```
  String body = String.Format(Template, getValue(r, "givenName"),strLValue);
  MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("aaa@qwe.com", getValue(r, "mail"), "Your password is about 
  to expire!", body);
```

But if i use embedded image ,I am unable to use other dynamically values or add the body. mm.AlternateViews.Add(Mail_Body());